# Angular2 - Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue with angular2, when I had created service, and attached it into `appModule` to `providers:[]` section, I had error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
    at SyntaxError.set [as stack] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:94:2), <anonymous>:1628:63)
    at assignAll (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2217:2), <anonymous>:704:29)
```

I have done two apps and I havent meet with similar error before...
This is my simple service file:

```
Injectable()
export class RecordService {

    private API_END_POINT: string = 'app/records';
    private API = process.env.API_END_POINT;

    constructor(private http: Http ) {

    }

    getRecords(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get( this.API_END_POINT )
            .map( (res:Response) => res.json().data as RecordModel )
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to fix that, there is no any information about this err nowhere... Please for help!

Comment: `Injectable()` should be `@Injectable()`. Did you add `HttpModule` to `imports: [...]`?

Comment: OMG, to much coding, I missed '@'... That was reason... eh, thanx mate!:)

Comment: I considered voting for closing the question, because it's merely a typo but the concrete error message you added might help others to find the mistake faster.

Comment: BTW, Gunter, this is not first time when you helped me;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there seems to be a bug in zone.js. Try fixing the version to 0.7.4 and see if the error message is more explicit

[check here for more info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3975)

> npm install --save zone.js@0.7.4

Comment: Problem solved, Thanks!:) Indeed stack doest shown template errors at all. Now it is ok!:)

Comment: aye aye thanks, this was so frustrating

Answer (score 2):

`Injectable()` is missing the `@`

it should be

```
@Injectable()
export class RecordService {
```

Comment: Can I ask for one thing? Actually all errors can't be displayed, because stack of errors is undefined. Before, you helped me find reason why I had err, but I need to investigate why my stack is always undefined if ng print stak...

Comment: What is `stack`? Your code doesn't show it.

Comment: stack - was stack trace:/ But I allready repaired it.